# How do i use DROP IF EXISTS for re-creating tables

Tags: mysql

I want to add more fields in profile table but when I try to add it says

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I had tried many things but nothing works for me.

Comment: what did you try? could you show us some code?

Answer (score 2):

to drop a table, if it exists you can use the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename;
```

have a look at the manual in the [DROP TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-table.html) part.

---

But if you simply want to add a column, you can use [`ALTER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/alter-table.html):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD newColumnName integer;
```

Comment: After adding a column, do i need to define that ?
i mean suppose there are 5 columns in profile table and i just define 3 columns then will it give me error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" ?

Comment: sry. i dont understand your problem. could you please give us more details about you tablestructure and the sql command which causes the error?